# Flutter pubspec dependency conflict

Tags: flutter, dart, package, pubspec

I've a wired problem with resolving dependencies. In my application pubspec I've following lines:

```yaml
dependencies:
  yet_another_layout_builder: ^0.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: ^1.1.1
```

both packages uses `analyzer` package and `flutter pub get` reports me an error:

```
Because no versions of hive_generator match >1.1.1 <2.0.0 and hive_generator 1.1.1 depends on analyzer >=1.0.0 <3.0.0, hive_generator ^1.1.1 requires analyzer >=1.0.0 <3.0.0.

And because every version of yet_another_layout_builder depends on analyzer ^3.0.0, hive_generator ^1.1.1 is incompatible with yet_another_layout_builder.

So, because testApp depends on both yet_another_layout_builder ^0.1.0 and hive_generator ^1.1.1, version solving failed.

pub get failed (1; So, because testApp depends on both yet_another_layout_builder ^0.1.0 and hive_generator ^1.1.1, version solving failed.)
```

However when I look into github sources for those packages, it looks for me that this error shouldn't happen. For `hive_generator` [pubspec](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/blob/master/hive_generator/pubspec.yaml) have following restrictions:

```yaml
dependencies:
  analyzer: ">=1.0.0 <4.0.0"
```

and for `YetAnotherLayoutBuilder` [pubspec](https://github.com/TheTosters/YetAnotherLayoutBuilder/blob/master/pubspec.yaml) have:

```yaml
dependencies:
  analyzer: ^3.0.0
```

So if I understands this notation correctly:

- YetAnotherLayoutBuilder expects analyzer in version >=3.0.0 and <4.0.0
- hive_generator expects analyzer in version >=1.0.0 and <4.0.0

Any suggestions where I'm mistaken are gladly welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now neither `hive_generator` plugin have any `upgrade` to this `version` nor `yet_another_layout_builder` has `downgrade` version. So to tackle these kinds of scenarios, we have another method to add `dependencies` in **Flutter** which is `dependency_overrides` using this we can `override` some `dependencies` so that our app can use another `version` of the same `dependency` as well. So just add below code to your **pubspecs.yaml** file

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: ^2.8.0
```